# Enable a single CGI script for Apache within the document root?

Tags: apache-2.4, python, cgi

Is it possible to enable a single CGI script stored within the Apache 2.4 document root ?

I was hoping something like the following might be possible :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "PATH/TO/htdocs/localhost"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost/errors.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost/access.log" common

    ScriptAlias "/python/" "PATH/TO/htdocs/localhost/python/index.py"
    <Files "PATH/TO/htdocs/localhost/python/index.py">
      Options +ExecCGI
      AddHandler cgi-script .py
      Require all granted
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

OR should I really be placing this within CGI-bin ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache really discourages the placement of scripts within ones htdocs. In my case this is for a fallback virtual host on a local development machine, so I can get away with the following :

```
PATH/TO/htdocs/localhost/index.html
PATH/TO/scripts/localhost/index.py
```

Specifying a `DirectoryIndex` indicates my preference for the python file over the static html file. The former then moved to a new location as indicated above.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "PATH/TO/htdocs/localhost"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost/errors.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost/access.log" common

    DirectoryIndex index.py index.php index.html

    ScriptAlias "/python/" "PATH/TO/scripts/localhost/python/index.py"
    <Files "PATH/TO/scripts/localhost/python/index.py">
      Options +ExecCGI
      AddHandler cgi-script .py
      Require all granted
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'll leave this as unanswered for the moment in case some one has a better suggestion. I'd be interested in any alternatives.